# Can anyone guide about eclipse and mysql configuration and connection completely

Tags: android, mysql

Can anyone guide about eclipse and mysql configuration and connection completely. I've visited many websites and see tutorials but did not found complete guidance. 
Guidline would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visit the tutorial [site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm), hope you will find your solution